# CSS animation with spin from center

Tags: css, html, animation

I am using css animations to try and get the green lines to spin around the red circle perfectly alined. I have linked to my fiddle where I have tried to get it working. any advice would be much appropriated. thanks!
 [fiddle][1]

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/3s07jbL4/3/
```

```css
 
.badge {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-50deg); 
    background:red;
}
span {
    font: 16px Monaco,monospace;
    height: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 34px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    transform-origin: center bottom 0px; 
    clip: rect(0px, 38px, 63px, 0px);
    background:green;
}
span img {
    width: 100%;
}
.day1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.day2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(12deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(12deg);
  transform: rotate(12deg);
}

.day3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(24deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(24deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(24deg);
  transform: rotate(24deg);
}

.day4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.day5 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(48deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(48deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(48deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(48deg);
  transform: rotate(48deg);
}

.day6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.day7 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(72deg);
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.day8 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(84deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(84deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(84deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(84deg);
  transform: rotate(84deg);
}

.day9 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(96deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(96deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(96deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(96deg);
  transform: rotate(96deg);
}

.day10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(108deg);
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.day11 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.day12 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(132deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(132deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(132deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(132deg);
  transform: rotate(132deg);
}

.day13 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(144deg);
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}

.day14 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(156deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(156deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(156deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(156deg);
  transform: rotate(156deg);
}

.day15 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(168deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(168deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(168deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(168deg);
  transform: rotate(168deg);
}

.day16 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.day17 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(192deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(192deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(192deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(192deg);
  transform: rotate(192deg);
}

.day18 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(204deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(204deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(204deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(204deg);
  transform: rotate(204deg);
}

.day19 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(216deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(216deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(216deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(216deg);
  transform: rotate(216deg);
}

.day20 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(228deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(228deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(228deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(228deg);
  transform: rotate(228deg);
}

.day21 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(240deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.day22 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(252deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(252deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(252deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(252deg);
  transform: rotate(252deg);
}

.day23 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(264deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(264deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(264deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(264deg);
  transform: rotate(264deg);
}

.day24 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(276deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(276deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(276deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(276deg);
  transform: rotate(276deg);
}

.day25 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(288deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(288deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(288deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(288deg);
  transform: rotate(288deg);
}
.day26 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.day27 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(312deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(312deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(312deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(312deg);
  transform: rotate(312deg);
}

.day28 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(324deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(324deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(324deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(324deg);
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}

.day29 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(336deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(336deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(336deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(336deg);
  transform: rotate(336deg);
}

.day30 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(348deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(348deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(348deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(348deg);
  transform: rotate(348deg);
}

.day31 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

    
 .badge
{
-webkit-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
-o-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
-ms-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
animation: spin1 2s infinite linear; 
width: 400px;
height: 400px;   
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-keyframes spin1 {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="spin">
  
  <div class="badge">  
      <span class="day1"> 
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day2"> 
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day3">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day4">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day5">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day6">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day7">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day8">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day9">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day10">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day11">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day12">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day13">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day14">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day15">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day16">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day17">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day18">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day19">
               1
            </span>
            <span class="day20">
1            </span>
            <span class="day21">
1            </span>
            <span class="day22">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day23">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day24">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day25">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day26">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day27">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day28">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day29">
                1
            </span>
            <span class="day30">
               1
            </span> 
  </div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: Im sorry I could not figure out how to link the way they wanted..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3s07jbL4/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center all of the `day` elements horizontally, add `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -17px` to the `span` elements. (`-17px` is because they are `34px` wide, and 17 is half of 34).

To center them vertically, add `margin-top: -40px` to them. This is because their heights are kind of arbitrary, and adding this will correct it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3s07jbL4/15/

Comment: Yeah.  May also need a position:absolute, I'm betting.

Comment: Which element? The `spans` are already `position: absolute`. Are you talking about the `.badge`?

Comment: Also, it's probably best if the `spans` have a class of `day` as well as their `day+number` class. Then change the `span` CSS to refer to `.day` instead.

Comment: You guys are awesome, thanks for the advice I defiantly just had some switches go off too. Answers + learning thanks!

Comment: -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom 0px; 
    -moz-transform-origin: center bottom 0px; 
    -ms-transform-origin: center bottom 0px; 
    -o-transform-origin: center bottom 0px;

Comment: `transform-origin` needs some `-webkit-transform-origin` as well, and you might as well add the other browsers too.